# How to control args[] in java main method?

Tags: java, args

I have to execute a jar in a command prompt having 2 argument.

1st arg = File Type
2nd arg = A file

Example: java -jar program.jar CSV My csvfile.csv

My problem is that when the main method is run, the args.length is equal to 3. And since I will read and process the file (My csvfile.csv), I am encountering a error that the file does not exists.

```
args[0] = CSV
args[1] = My
args[2] = csvfile.csv

Can I make it like:
args[0] = CSV
args[1] = My csvfile.csv
```

There was no assumption that the filename should not have spaces.

Comment: Use quotes on the command line.

Comment: Wrap the file name in quotes?

Comment: Thanks guys.. I didn't know that.. It works. :)